# enumeration using tabular

Tags: tabularx, enumitem

I guess the best way to explain my problem is to show a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{arydshln}

\begin{document}
\section{Tab}
\begin{tabular}{  p{6cm} p{8cm} }
\hline
Title A & Text A.1 \\
\hdashline[3pt/1.5pt]
& Text A.2 \\
\hdashline[3pt/1.5pt]
& Text A.3 \\
\hdashline[3pt/1.5pt]
Title B & Text B.1 \\
\hline
%
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

I would like to put "a)" in front of Title A, "b)" in front of Title B and so on.
So the enumeration should 'go on' each time I type in a title in the first column.
How can I force this?

Comment: the simplest way is add `a)`, `b)` manualy before title. or write as standard enumerate ...

Answer (score 1):

While agreeing with Zarko's comment, you might want to try

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\newcounter{mycount}\renewcommand{\themycount}{\alph{mycount}}
\newcommand{\myit}{\refstepcounter{mycount}\themycount)~}
\begin{document}
\section{Tab}
\begin{tabular}{  p{6cm} p{8cm} }
\hline
\myit Title A & Text A.1 \\
\hdashline[3pt/1.5pt]
& Text A.2 \\
\hdashline[3pt/1.5pt]
& Text A.3 \\
\hdashline[3pt/1.5pt]
\myit  Title B & Text B.1 \\
\hline
%
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]